# PHP line goes downwards after update to database

Tags: php, html

So if i type text to my textbox, then I press submit button, wich sends data to update.php and update.php sends data to my database, then update.php redirects back to edit.php and the textbox whole text has gone downwards, any ideas ?

Edit.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="update.php">

    Meist<br>
    <textarea style="resize:none" cols="100" rows="10" method="post" type="text" id="meist" name="meist"><?php

        include_once("connect.php");

        $sql = 'SELECT meist FROM content WHERE id=1';

        mysql_select_db('fava');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval )
        {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo    "{$row['meist']}";
        } 
        mysql_close($conn);

        ?>
        </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="salvesta"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

update.php

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "fava";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$meist =$_POST["meist"];
$id = 1;
// query
$sql = "UPDATE content SET meist=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($meist,$id));
echo "Edukalt salvestatud";
header('Refresh: 2; URL=http://localhost/php_sandbox/edit.php');



?>
```

If any questions then shoot, because it is kind of hard to explain.

Comment: What does 'gone downwards' mean?

Comment: Do you mean it is adding a carriage return before the saved text?

Comment: @Joosep Kudos for using PDO

Comment: @Rottingham Kudos ? and it is automatically breaking line, thats what i mean by "goes downwards"

Comment: Kudos = Good job, props, +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, get all that PHP code OUT of the  content area. Since you are including the connect.php file, it is literally putting the contents of connect.php inside the textarea item. If there are new line characters in connect.php, like at the end of the file, it will create a blank line in the textarea input.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php

    include_once("connect.php");

    $sql = 'SELECT meist FROM content WHERE id=1';
    $text = '';

    mysql_select_db('fava');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $text .= "{$row['meist']}";
    } 
    mysql_close($conn);

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="update.php">

    Meist<br>
    <textarea style="resize:none" cols="100" rows="10" method="post" type="text" id="meist" name="meist">
        <?php echo $text; ?>
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="salvesta"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I am created a blank $text variable and filling it with the data you want to have in the  field and when all the work is done, we are echoing only that item in the  content.

This cleans up the code, makes it clear what you are doing and makes sure stray new line characters are being implanted where you don't want them.

Comment: Now it creates quite lots of spaces horizontally. Before your code it vent vertically down, now it goes horizontally right...

Comment: aah found the problem... <?php and <textbox> tags have to be against each other, meaning that there cant be no space...

Comment: @JoosepSisas Good Catch! If this answer works for you, click the big check mark next to my answer so it marks this question as answered